# Javafx application dialog not closing when I open it the secon time

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am opening my dialog from this code which in is my main controller called `InvoicecreationController`. When I open the dialog for the first time and I select a row and press the Enter key it closes. However, when I open it for the second time, it is not closing.

```java
public void openitemsearchPopWindow(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/AccApp/customers/newinvoice/modals/ItemSearchResults.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        ItemSearchResultsController enteritemNameforsearchController = loader.getController();
        enteritemNameforsearchController.getupdateinvoiceController(this);

        Stage stageSearchedSupplier = new Stage();
        stageSearchedSupplier.setScene(new Scene(root));           
        stageSearchedSupplier.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stageSearchedSupplier.initOwner(customername.getScene().getWindow());
        stageSearchedSupplier.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);            
        stageSearchedSupplier.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(invoicecreationController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

My code for the dialog controller is below.

```
@FXML
public TableView<Itemnames> seachedresultsTable;

@FXML
public TableColumn<Itemnames, String> itemnameCol;

@FXML
public TextField searchtextfield;

@FXML
public AnchorPane rootPane;

private invoicecreationController invoicecreationcontroller;

public void getupdateinvoiceController(invoicecreationController invoicecreationcontroller) {
    this.invoicecreationcontroller = invoicecreationcontroller;
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    seachedresultsTable.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue,
                Number newValue) {

            TableHeaderRow header = (TableHeaderRow) seachedresultsTable.lookup("TableHeaderRow");
            header.reorderingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                        Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    header.setReordering(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    seachedresultsTable.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                String myIndex = seachedresultsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getName();
                if (!"".equals(myIndex)) {
                    invoicecreationcontroller.updateTableCell(myIndex);
                    Stage stage = (Stage) searchtextfield.getScene().getWindow();
                    stage.close();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    itemnameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    loadItemNames();
}
private ObservableList<Itemnames> data;
List<Itemnames> itemnameList;
```

Comment: `seachedresultsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getName()` returns a not empty string so your code closes the window. It is not that hard to figure out

Comment: [mcv] please ..

Comment: It is not closing if I open it for the second time - fuggerjaki61.